# How to check if data was successfuly written to firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to check if data was written successfuly to Firestore so if it was successful I need to show a popup showing data was written or if data wasn't written i need to show a popup showing task failed so should I use a future builder what is the way to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every Firestore Operations are promises, so it has **.then()** and **.catch()** method to handle whether the task is successful or failure. 
For example, you can do something like this.

```
 firestoreInstance.collection("Users").document('123456').updateData({
 
  "username" : 'white_devil'

 }).then((result) {
   
   print("Success!");

 }).catch((error){
 
   print("Error!")

});
```

Not only on `updateData()`, you can also use this case in `setData()`,`add()`,`get()`, `getDocuments()` and all operations which returns a  promise.

Comment: The answer helped thank you  but just for future understanding so what if I had used future builder can I accomplish the same task or is it not meant to be used that way why is one prefered over the other

Comment: No. This method is not advisable for FutureBuilder. But there is another way to do that.
You can use `snapshot.hasError` to check the `future` has some error. Further Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo

Answer (score 1):

You should use a catch block on the returned promise to check for errors. If the catch is not triggering, we can show a successful warning. This is the way all dart futures work.

See the documentation: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling